# Create and modify the contents of a VDI disk image in Linux

Tags: linux, virtualbox, ntfs, vdi

Is there any way I can create a Virtual Box disk image (.vdi) that is NTFS formatted and copy a set of files to it prior to attaching it to an already configured instance as a second disk using VBoxManage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you will have to:

1. "Aattch" the VDI file as another disk device
2. "Mount" NTFS partitions in that VDI file

Ways of doing that are described in this post:

https://serverfault.com/questions/210684/how-do-you-mount-a-vdi-image-on-linux